# Unity can't build to windows platform for HoloLens

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I've followed the Microsoft documentation for building mixed reality application. I did not have a problem making the app, the application runs in the editor without a problem. However, I can't build the application, this is the error:

I've checked the preference, cleaned out the cache, checked the information on the player setting and XR virtual reality: mixed reality is ticked.

Invalid build path: d:/unity_projects/holoworld
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Can you tell us about your D partition, and the folder you're using?  I'd suspect some kind of permissions problem.  A way to rule this out would be to try again from your C drive.

Comment: I build it on the desktop and it worked fine, however, doesn't work when I output to the folder...

Comment: You can't build your project to the same directory as your Unity Project. Make a subdirectory.

Comment: thanks for that, I've done that and it works GREAT!